# subtraction turns into multiplication

Tags: python

I am still very new to coding and I'm following a yt tutorial on python. In the tutorial, I made a very simple calculator that just does addition and that's all. So, I thought I would try to make a slightly more complicated one that can do more than just addition. So, I tried and it mostly works, but when I try to subtract it multiplies. Everything else works fine. It's just subtraction that doesn't work. The only time it works is if I type "-" so I decided to try and make everything a symbol. I tried it and now it's only multiplying. So, next, I decided to change this

```
elif mathForm >= '-':

print(float(num1) - float(num2))
```

to this

```
else: 
    print(float(num1) - float(num2))"
```

and it still doesn't work. I really don't understand what's happening. Please help. Here is the rest of the code if needed.

```
mathForm = input("what form of math do you want to do ")

num1 = input('what is your first number ')*

num2 = input('what is you second number ')*


if mathForm >= 'multiply':

    *print(float(num1) * float(num2))*

elif mathForm >= 'divide':

    print(float(num1) / float(num2))*

elif mathForm >= 'add':
    print(float(num1) + float(num2))

elif mathForm >= '-':
    print(float(num1) - float(num2))*
```

Comment: Use `==`, not `>=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `>=` rather than `==` to compare the user's `mathForm` input with your operations. This tests if the input is alphabetically equal to or higher than the string. `"subtract" >= "multiply"` is true because `s` is later in the alphabet than `m`.

Use `==` to perform exact matches, rather than `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `==` operator because you are checking for equivalence when it comes to strings.

```
mathform = input("what form of math do you want to do ")
num1 = input('what is your first number ')
num2 = input('what is you second number ')

if mathForm == 'multiply':
    print(float(num1) * float(num2))

elif mathForm == 'divide':
    print(float(num1) / float(num2))

elif mathForm == 'add':
    print(float(num1) + float(num2))

elif mathForm == 'subtract':
    print(float(num1) - float(num2))
```

Alternatively you can also do this,

```
mathForm = input("what form of math do you want to do ")
num1 = input('what is your first number ')
num2 = input('what is you second number ')

if mathForm == '*':
    print(float(num1) * float(num2))

elif mathForm == '/':
    print(float(num1) / float(num2))

elif mathForm == '+':
    print(float(num1) + float(num2))

elif mathForm == '-':
    print(float(num1) - float(num2))
```

Use the keywords multiple, divide, add and subtract instead of the minus sign to keep it consistent. Or use the symbols in all of them.

Comment: @potatognome please tick my answer if it helped! Thanks :)